# Passing variables by reference to avoid global variables and extern

Tags: c++, variables, struct

I have had written my program but it was relying solely on the use of global variables and extern. I have decided to work on fixing my code and make it as simple as possible. However, It seems to be going in the wrong direction. I have 3 structures that are used pretty much everywhere in my code:

1. item_inside_struct
2. device_info
3. encoder_struct.

I have written a wrapper for the tft display. The tft display must know all the states of the 3 structs since it is displaying everything on the screen. So I pass these structs to my tft functions as a reference. But since the tft functions are being called elsewhere in the code ( it could be main.c or even invoked in other source files), the structures must be passed to other functions that invoke tft methods as well.

For example: I have written sensor.c and sensor.h. It contains all the sensor functions. After the sensor is read, based on the sensor result, it may need to do update tft display hence I must pass all the structure data to the function that performs reading the sensor even though the function itself does not care about these 3 structures apart from the ftf update function. My sensor.c :

```
void Read_sensor_no_delay(item_inside_struct* item_inside, device_info* device, encoder_struct* encoder){
  if(sensor_disable == 0){
  if(strncmp(item_inside->state, "PILDYMAS", 8) != 0)
  {
    sensor = digitalRead(SENSOR);
    if(sensor==LOW  && sensor_prev_state==HIGH)// SENSOR ON
    {
        sensor_prev_state=LOW; // set the previous state to LOW
        if (strncmp(item_inside->state,"ACTIVE",6)!=0){ // IF NUMBER TO PICK ITEMS IS 0, SET RED LIGHT TO SHOW OPERATOR WRONG BOX
          handle_wrong_box(item_inside,device,encoder);
        }
    
    }
    else if(sensor==HIGH && sensor_prev_state==LOW) //SENSOR DEACTIVATED
    { 
      if(item_inside->num_to_pick > 0 && (strncmp(item_inside->state,"ACTIVE",6)==0) )// if number_to_pick >0, and device is activated, take items  
      { 
        handle_active_device(item_inside,device,encoder);
        sensor_disable = 1;
        lastMsg2 = millis();
      }   
        else if(strncmp(item_inside->state,"ACTIVE",6)!=0)
        {
          handle_not_active_device(item_inside,device,encoder);
        }
        sensor_prev_state = HIGH;

    }
  }

  }
  
  else{
      if (now - lastMsg2 > 4000) 
      {
          //Serial.println("5 seconds passed");
          sensor_disable=0;
      }
  }
  
}







void handle_wrong_box(item_inside_struct* item_inside, device_info* device, encoder_struct* encoder){
  turn_ON_timer();
  LED_strip_ON(red,PixelCount);     
  update_screen_colour(ST77XX_RED,item_inside,device,encoder);
}




void handle_active_device(item_inside_struct* item_inside, device_info* device, encoder_struct* encoder){
          
          sensor_prev_state = HIGH;         
          item_inside->num_to_pick--;
          item_inside->quantity--;
          mb.Hreg(MAIN_REG, 12);    //PUT 55 IN REG1
          mb.Hreg(NUMBER_TO_PICK_REG, item_inside->quantity);    // register 24
          update_screen_colour(ST77XX_BLACK,item_inside,device,encoder); 
          strcpy(item_inside->state,"DONE");
          turn_ON_timer2();
          if(item_inside->quantity <=10)
            {

            }
            return;
}



void handle_not_active_device(item_inside_struct* item_inside, device_info* device, encoder_struct* encoder){
    turn_OFF_timer();
    LED_strip_ON(black,PixelCount);  
    update_screen_colour(ST77XX_BLACK,item_inside,device,encoder);
    sensor_prev_state = HIGH;
}
```

Notice the `read_sensor_no_delay()` function only needs to know about item_inside_struct, but does not care about device_info or encoder_struct, but I still must pass those to the function. Further down in `read_sensor_no_delay()` function the other function is called`handle_wrong_box()`. This function will redraw the display and display the new data therefore it must know all 3 structures.

My tft.c:

```
#include "tft_custom.h"



int screen_colour = ST77XX_BLACK ;
int local_quantity = 0;
int local_number_to_pick = 0;
char local_eeprom_serial[10]="NONE";
char local_current_status[20] = "NONE";
int local_displaycounter = 0;
char local_device_id[10] = "NONE";
char local_device_version[10] = "NONE";
char local_mqtt_server[20] = "NONE";

Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);





void TFT_setup(){
  tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);
  tft.setRotation(3);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE, ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
}



void TFT_display_update(item_inside_struct* item_inside,device_info* device, encoder_struct* encoder){    
    tft.setTextSize(4); 

    if(local_quantity != item_inside->quantity)
    {
      tft.setCursor(0, 0);
      tft.fillRect(0,0, 80, 32, screen_colour);
      local_quantity = item_inside->quantity;
      tft.print(local_quantity);   //quantity inside          
   
    }

    
    if(local_number_to_pick != item_inside->num_to_pick)
    {
      tft.setCursor(0,32);  
      tft.fillRect(0,32, 40, 32, screen_colour); 
      local_number_to_pick = item_inside->num_to_pick;               
      tft.print(local_number_to_pick);        // number2 means number to_pick
    }
    
    tft.setTextSize(1); 

      if(strcmp(local_device_version,device->device_version)!= 0)
    {
      tft.setCursor(120,0);  
      tft.fillRect(120,0, 10, 10, screen_colour);
      strcpy(local_device_version,device->device_version);          
      tft.print(local_device_version);        // number2 means number to_pick
    }

    
        if(strcmp(local_mqtt_server,device->mqtt_server)!= 0)
    {
      tft.setCursor(80,10);  
      tft.fillRect(80,10, 40, 5, screen_colour);                
      strcpy(local_mqtt_server,device->mqtt_server);
      tft.print(local_mqtt_server);        // number2 means number to_pick
    }
    
    tft.setTextSize(2);
    if(strcmp(local_device_id,device->DEVICE_ID)!= 0){ 
      tft.setCursor(40,60);
      tft.fillRect(40,60, 50, 16, screen_colour);    
      strcpy(local_device_id,device->DEVICE_ID);
      tft.print(local_device_id); 
      
    }     


    if(strcmp(local_current_status,item_inside->state)!= 0){ 
      tft.setCursor(40,32);
      tft.fillRect(40,32, 120, 16, screen_colour);  
      strcpy(local_current_status,item_inside->state);
      tft.print(local_current_status); 

    }  
             
    if(strcmp(local_eeprom_serial,item_inside->serial) !=0)
    {
      tft.setCursor(40,76);
      tft.fillRect(40,76, 120, 16, screen_colour);  
      strcpy(local_eeprom_serial, item_inside->serial);
      tft.print(local_eeprom_serial);      //print SERIAL id

  
    }
    
    if(local_displaycounter != encoder->displaycounter)
    {
      tft.setCursor(40,94); 
      tft.fillRect(40,94, 60, 16, screen_colour);   
      local_displaycounter = encoder->displaycounter;
      tft.print(local_displaycounter/10);      //print SERIAL id
    }
  
}
void TFT_display(item_inside_struct* item_inside,device_info* device, encoder_struct* encoder){   
    //tft.fillRect(0,0, 160, 80, ST77XX_BLACK);  
    tft.setTextSize(4); 
    tft.setCursor(0, 0);    
    tft.print(item_inside->quantity);   //quantity inside          
    tft.setCursor(0,32);                  
    tft.print(item_inside->num_to_pick);        // number2 means number to_pick
    tft.setTextSize(1); 

    tft.setCursor(120,0);
    tft.print(device->device_version);
     
    tft.setCursor(80,10);             
    tft.print(device->mqtt_server);        // number2 means number to_pick

      

    tft.setTextSize(2); 
    tft.setCursor(64,32);
    tft.print(item_inside->state);        
    tft.setCursor(40,60); 
    tft.print(device->DEVICE_ID);        
    tft.setCursor(40,76);  
    tft.print(item_inside->serial);      //print SERIAL id
    tft.setCursor(40,94);  
    tft.print(encoder->displaycounter/10);      //print SERIAL id
    

}


void update_screen_colour(int background_colour,item_inside_struct* item_inside, device_info* device, encoder_struct* encoder)
{
  screen_colour=background_colour;
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE, background_colour);
  tft.fillScreen(background_colour);
  TFT_display(item_inside,device,encoder);
}
```

Now I pretty much pass these 3 structs to every single function in my code because at some point tft update method will be called. Could someone point me in the right direction how this ugly code could be improved?

**Trying to write tft class**

I have rewritten my tft.c and tft.h and learned quite a bit in the process.
My tft.c :

```
include "tft_custom.h"


//class constructor, pass the 3 structures here
TFT::TFT(item_inside_struct &item_inside, device_info &device, encoder_struct &encoder){
  Serial.println("calling tft class constructor");
  screen_colour = ST77XX_BLACK ;
  local_quantity = 0;
  local_number_to_pick = 0;
  local_displaycounter = 0;
  strcpy(local_eeprom_serial,"NONE");
  strcpy(local_current_status,"NONE");
  strcpy(local_device_id,"NONE");
  strcpy(local_device_version,"NONE");
  strcpy(local_mqtt_server,"NONE");
  class_item_inside = &item_inside;
  class_device = &device;
  class_encoder = &encoder;
}
void TFT::begin(){
  tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);
  tft.setRotation(3);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE, ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
}


void TFT::update_display_once(){

    tft.setTextSize(4); 
    tft.setCursor(0, 0);    
    tft.print(class_item_inside->quantity);   //quantity inside          
    tft.setCursor(0,32);                  
    tft.print(class_item_inside->num_to_pick);        // number2 means number to_pick
    tft.setTextSize(1); 

    tft.setCursor(120,0);
    tft.print(class_device->device_version);
     
    tft.setCursor(80,10);             
    tft.print(class_device->mqtt_server);        // number2 means number to_pick

      

    tft.setTextSize(2); 
    tft.setCursor(64,32);
    tft.print(class_item_inside->state);        
    tft.setCursor(40,60); 
    tft.print(class_device->DEVICE_ID);        
    tft.setCursor(40,76);  
    tft.print(class_item_inside->serial);      //print SERIAL id
    tft.setCursor(40,94);  
    tft.print(class_encoder->displaycounter/10);      //print SERIAL id

}


void TFT::TFT_display_update(){    
    tft.setTextSize(4); 
    if(local_quantity != class_item_inside->quantity)
    {
      tft.setCursor(0, 0);
      tft.fillRect(0,0, 80, 32, screen_colour);
      local_quantity = class_item_inside->quantity;
      tft.print(local_quantity);   //quantity inside          
   
    }

    
    if(local_number_to_pick != class_item_inside->num_to_pick)
    {
      tft.setCursor(0,32);  
      tft.fillRect(0,32, 40, 32, screen_colour); 
      local_number_to_pick = class_item_inside->num_to_pick;               
      tft.print(local_number_to_pick);        // number2 means number to_pick
    }
    
    tft.setTextSize(1); 

      if(strcmp(local_device_version,class_device->device_version)!= 0)
    {
      tft.setCursor(120,0);  
      tft.fillRect(120,0, 10, 10, screen_colour);
      strcpy(local_device_version,class_device->device_version);          
      tft.print(local_device_version);        // number2 means number to_pick
    }

    
        if(strcmp(local_mqtt_server,class_device->mqtt_server)!= 0)
    {
      tft.setCursor(80,10);  
      tft.fillRect(80,10, 40, 5, screen_colour);                
      strcpy(local_mqtt_server,class_device->mqtt_server);
      tft.print(local_mqtt_server);        // number2 means number to_pick
    }
    
    tft.setTextSize(2);
    if(strcmp(local_device_id,class_device->DEVICE_ID)!= 0){ 
      tft.setCursor(40,60);
      tft.fillRect(40,60, 50, 16, screen_colour);    
      strcpy(local_device_id,class_device->DEVICE_ID);
      tft.print(local_device_id); 
      
    }     


    if(strcmp(local_current_status,class_item_inside->state)!= 0){ 
      tft.setCursor(40,32);
      tft.fillRect(40,32, 120, 16, screen_colour);  
      strcpy(local_current_status,class_item_inside->state);
      tft.print(local_current_status); 

    }  
             
    if(strcmp(local_eeprom_serial,class_item_inside->serial) !=0)
    {
      tft.setCursor(40,76);
      tft.fillRect(40,76, 120, 16, screen_colour);  
      strcpy(local_eeprom_serial, class_item_inside->serial);
      tft.print(local_eeprom_serial);      //print SERIAL id

  
    }
    
    if(local_displaycounter != class_encoder->displaycounter)
    {
      tft.setCursor(40,94); 
      tft.fillRect(40,94, 60, 16, screen_colour);   
      local_displaycounter = class_encoder->displaycounter;
      tft.print(local_displaycounter/10);      //print SERIAL id
    }
  
}




void TFT::update_screen_colour(int background_colour)
{
  screen_colour=background_colour;
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE, background_colour);
  tft.fillScreen(background_colour);
  update_display_once();
}
```

and tft.h:

```
#ifndef TFT_CUSTOM_H
#define TFT_CUSTOM_H

#include "Adafruit_ST7735.h" // Hardware-specific library for ST7735
#include "SPI.h"
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "definitions.h"

#define TFT_CS        5 // Hallowing display control pins: chip select
#define TFT_RST       4 // Display reset
#define TFT_DC        2 // Display data/command select
#define TFT_MOSI 19  // Data out
#define TFT_SCLK 18  // Clock out





class TFT
{

private:
  Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);
  //create 3 pointers to the struct
  item_inside_struct *class_item_inside; 
  device_info *class_device;
  encoder_struct *class_encoder;
  int screen_colour;
  int local_quantity;
  int local_number_to_pick;
  char local_eeprom_serial[10];
  char local_current_status[20];
  int local_displaycounter;
  char local_device_id[10] ;
  char local_device_version[10];
  char local_mqtt_server[20];

public:
TFT(item_inside_struct &item_inside, device_info &device, encoder_struct &encoder);
void begin();
void update_display_once();
void TFT_display_update();
void update_screen_colour(int background_colour);

};

#endif
```

In my main.c I create a class constructor and pass the 3 structures. Inside a class constructor, I create a pointers for all 3 structures and I use these 3 pointers throughout the whole  class

my main.c:

```
TFT tft_object(item_inside, device, encoder);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(SENSOR, INPUT);    // sets the digital pin 13 as output
  Expander_SETUP();
  setup_leds();
  tft_object.begin();
  tft_object.update_display_once();
}

void loop() {
  if(strncmp(item_inside.state, "PILDYMAS", 8) != 0)
  {
  Read_sensor_no_delay(tft_object);
  }
```

Notice in my read_sensor_no_delay function, I pass this the tft object.
And inside the read_sensor function I want to be able to read and write to the class object structures as shown below:

```
void Read_sensor_no_delay(TFT &tft_object ){
    sensor = digitalRead(SENSOR);
    if(sensor==LOW  && sensor_prev_state==HIGH)// SENSOR ON
    {

     if (strncmp(tft_object.class_item_inside->state,"ACTIVE",6)!=0){ // IF NUMBER TO PICK ITEMS IS 0, SET RED LIGHT TO SHOW OPERATOR WRONG BOX

        handle_activation(tft_object);
    }
    
    else if(sensor==HIGH && sensor_prev_state==LOW) //SENSOR DEACTIVATED
    { 
        handle_deactivation(tft_object);
    }

}
```

Notice  `if (strncmp(tft_object.class_item_inside->state,"ACTIVE",6)!=0)` inside read sensor function. However, I am getting an issue due to all the variables in my tft class declared as private. Is the only way to solve this issue declare the 3 pointers to the structure public?

Comment: My 2¢ is to adopt [TDD](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/effective-tdd-10-books-get-you-started-junilu-lacar) techniques to help guide refactoring the code.

Comment: It's called "classes", which is one of C++'s fundamental principles. Turn your code into methods of a class, and have as many "global" variables as you wish, as class members.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I do not understand how classes going to help me solve the problem. As I mentioned, almost every single source file in my code needs to be aware of these structs so either they must be global or must be passed as a reference. How a class can help me save this issue?

Comment: There is no law in C++ that requires all class methods to be in a single source file.

Comment: Apparently there's something meaningful about this combination of three struct objects, even if that thing is "the current overall state of the entire program". Which suggests maybe they should be represented by a single type containing or pointing at the others.

Comment: @aschepler yes that would simplify things quite a bit. I did not do that because each struct coressponds to a very different data. But even if I do that, I still must pass this one structure arround the whole program

Comment: it happens in many program that you need some variable that are conceptually "global", and the temptation is to keep it global and avoid passing it's address /reference all around.
This usually lead to an hard to maintain program. Something I find useful in such case is to follow the [Single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle): one class, one responsibility. You usually end finding that there is a lot of code that doesn't require the "global " variables,

Answer (score 1):

There is no right answer of course.  If you try to come up with one, a bunch of people will hop on and tell you why its wrong :-)

But, a few choices:

1. It's actually ok to have global variables.  It makes it harder for people to understand the code and where values are coming from, etc, but it's technically not "wrong" (ie, it compiles so the compiler thinks its ok right?).  You can also use `goto` statements as well, and that's considered "bad" by many as well.
2. Some code encapsulates local copies of variables they need to know about within `static` variables in a file. Then you can create an `init_sensors()` function that takes those three pointers and remembers them.
3. Another common mechanism, probably preferred by most in raw-C code, is to create a single pointer that encapsulates the three other structures and to pass that pointer around instead as the first argument to pretty much every function.  This also future-proofs your code a bit in case you ever need to add a fourth.  Something like:

```c
struct foo_context {
   item_inside_struct* item_inside;
   device_info* device;
   encoder_struct* encoder;
}
```

4. You're using C++ but much of the code feels more "C" like.  Getting a better handle on the object oriented nature might be helpful as well and trying to encapsulate more of the functionality into the objects.  IE, if the `TFT*` functions were wrapped inside a new TFT object, then you could create that object once, pass the pointers in during its constructor and have it memorize them while the class' instance is alive.

Comment: Thank you for the response sir. I think I should really learn more about object oriented programming. I can rewrite my tft.c and tft.h files and create a tft class with constructor and various methods. Would that allow me to use tft methods in other source files? I am still concerned how am I going to pass these 3 structrs arround. Would I pass them into my tft class constructor as a parameters and then I can envoke each tft class method without additionally passing these structs?

Comment: Basically, yes.  And yes, OOP takes a while to get used to switching your brain around to thinking of objects as containers of data and functionality.  Some people, of course, take it "too far" and make everything objects when that's not always needed.  Finding the right balance is key.

Comment: Okay. I will do that tommorow and see if I can come up with something. Il post my findings here. Thanks

Comment: Hello sir. I have rewritten my tft library like a class. Could you point me in the right direction on what would be the best way to pass the 3 structures to the constructor? I have updated my initial question and put all my code in there so you can see what is going on. I tried to be as clear as possible

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not a complete answer, just a pointer towards separating responsibilities, which others mentioned already.

Let's see this part:

> After the sensor is read, based on the sensor result, it may need to do update tft display hence I must pass all the structure data to the function

This [smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) bad. The code reading a sensor needs not know about the tft display. There may be multiple objects which would need to give some feedback or other reaction on the sensor's state change – displaying something, blinking some LED, beeping an acoustic signal, logging the event in some file, etc, etc. You just *can't* know all possible future objects which will need to be updated. And your code must not depend on classes representing those objects.

A solution can be a message broker – an object who knows different participants and transfers messages between them (see [Message broker at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker)). This can be simply an object of a main application class: the `item_inside_struct` can contain a pointer to an `App` object and that would be responsible for proper handling (i.e. dispatching) events to other devices.

Another approach may be an observer (see [Observer pattern at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)) – all objects of different classes in your application, which may utilize changes of the sensor's state somehow, would register in the sensor class object (i.e. by appending themselves to the list) and will be notified whenever a change is recognized. Then each of them will produce appropriate response without being known in details to the sensor's class.

Comment: Yes I totally agree that sensor does not care at all about the tft.. But I still cant fully understand how to properly structure my sensor code. For example I have the following code:```if(sensor == 1) { handle_sensor_activation(); } else { handle_sensor_deactivation();}``` . The handle_sensor functions will need to do something as a result of sensor toggling ON or OFF. Could you provide some example how handle function can handle the event of TFT or LED ?

Comment: I have made some progress with classes. You can see my updated initial question. Now instead of passing 3 structs arround everwyhere, I can pass the tft class object instead. This saves me 2 additional variables so the code looks a bit cleaner. However, the tft class object must be passed to the sensor function so it is still not a perfect code where all source files are independant of each other as you mentioned.